# what is {image-data} in facebook android sdk

Tags: android, facebook

here is the facebook sample

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putString("source", "{image-data}");
/* make the API call */
new Request(
    session,
    "/me/photos",
    params,
    HttpMethod.POST,
    new Request.Callback() {
        public void onCompleted(Response response) {
            /* handle the result */
        }
    }
).executeAsync();
```

what is {image-data}

I tried use byte[].toString, file.toString, path of file.  not work.
so how to upload photo with this api?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

facebook doc is wrong.
change

```
params.putString("source", "{image-data}");
```

to

```
params.putByteArray("source", "{image-data}");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to post a photo, use one of the Request.newUploadPhotoRequest methods, it will set everything up for you.

See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/class/Request/#newUploadPhotoRequest